# Niveis de acesso Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou criando um sistema em que vou ter niveis de acesso, a minha dúvida é em como colocar para que em projeto x , tal usuário tenha acesso e em projeto y ,outro usuário tenha acesso. Alguma dica ou função para fazer isso no wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Wordpress possui 6 [níveis](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Pap%C3%A9is_e_Capacidades) básicos de acesso e permissões.

O que seriam esses projetos?

Um CMS com mais recursos como o Drupal, lhe permite gerir melhor as permissões, pois você pode criar tipos de conteúdo (que seriam os projetos) e papeis para atribuir e refinar tais permissões.

Se você não pretende codificar, nativamente o Drupal já lhe provê tais recursos.